# R and S Lie Subalgebra usp$_4$ to su$_2$ gives several different results -- how are they related?

Tags: group-theory, modules, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

We know that the Lie algebra
$$usp_4 \sim sp_2  \sim so_5.$$

It is said in https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kFuSDO_3apXes45FH3YPa4s4HEZd9Vj9/view:

"There are two types of subalgebras of simple Lie algebras defined by E.B. Dynkin. One is an R-subalgebra; the other is an S-subalgebra. An R-subalgebra is a subalgebra that contains several regular subalgebras, where all R-subalgebras is obtained by deleting dots from (extended) Dynkin diagrams. An S-subalgebra is a subalgebra that is not any R-subalgebra. It can be found by using dimensions and type of irreducible representations of a Lie algebra and its subalgebra. (Some S-subalgebras can be found by using (extended) Dynkin diagrams but it is difficult to find almost all S-subalgebras. The rank of an S-subalgebra is always smaller than the rank of its original Lie algebra.)"

[image]

> question: I am not sure why for example by the branch rule from $usp_4 \sim sp_2  \sim so_5$ to $su_2$ gives several different results?

See Table F.3.2.1

usp_4  to su_2 (S):
$$
4 = 4,
$$
$$
5=5 
$$

But See Table F.3.1.1

usp_4  to su_2 + su_2 (R):
$$
4 = (2,1)+(1,2),
$$
$$
5= (2,2)+(1,1).
$$

But See Table F.3.1.2
usp_4  to su_2 + u_1 (R):
$$
4 = 2_1+2_{-1},
$$
$$
5= 3_0 + 1_2 + 1_{-2}.
$$

> Why are they different? and how R and S Lie subalgebra related?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "Why are they different?" -- Because one restricts to different subalgebras?

Comment: but how are they related? they all have a Lie subalgebra $su_2$. I wanted to see a relation between each Lie subalgebra $su_2$. say if we only restrict to one of Lie subalgebra $su_2$