# R and S Lie Subalgebra $su_4$ to $su_2$ gives several different results — how are they related?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, dynkin-diagrams

We know that the Lie algebra
$$su_4   \sim so_6.$$

It is said in https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kFuSDO_3apXes45FH3YPa4s4HEZd9Vj9/view:

"There are two types of subalgebras of simple Lie algebras defined by E.B. Dynkin. One is an R-subalgebra; the other is an S-subalgebra. An R-subalgebra is a subalgebra that contains several regular subalgebras, where all R-subalgebras is obtained by deleting dots from (extended) Dynkin diagrams. An S-subalgebra is a subalgebra that is not any R-subalgebra. It can be found by using dimensions and type of irreducible representations of a Lie algebra and its subalgebra. (Some S-subalgebras can be found by using (extended) Dynkin diagrams but it is difficult to find almost all S-subalgebras. The rank of an S-subalgebra is always smaller than the rank of its original Lie algebra.)"

[image]

> question: I am not sure why for example by the branch rule from $su_4 $ to $su_2$ gives several different results?

See Table F.1.4.2

su_4  to su_2 + su_2 (S):
$$
4 = (2,2),
$$
$$
\bar{4}= (2,2),
$$
$$
6=(1,3) +(3,1). 
$$

But See Table F.1.3.2

su_4  to su_2 + su_2 + u_1 (R):
$$
4 = (2,1)_{1}+(1,2)_{-1},
$$
$$
\bar{4}= (2,1)_{-1}+(1,2)_{1},
$$
$$
6=(1,1)_2 +(2,2)_0+(1,1)_{-2}. 
$$

> Why are they different? and how R and S Lie subalgebra related?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Annie, just letting you know you posted your question twice.

Comment: Thanks but No, I asked two related but very different questions

Comment: A related but different question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3782474/141334

Comment: No, that's the same question, namely number 3782474. For the very similar one see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782457/r-and-s-lie-subalgebra-usp-4-to-su-2-gives-several-different-results-how).

Comment: One is from su4 to su2. The other question is from usp4 to su2. The su4 and usp4 are different. The answers are also different.